# Calling an external API whenever a field in the database is updated

Tags: c#, postgresql, model-view-controller, asp.net-core

My `ApplicationUser` model contains a property:

```
public bool SubscribedToNewsletter { get;set; }
```

I would like to make sure that whenever I update its value in the database, an external API will be called to add or remove the user from a list in my email automation system, without manually calling the method myself to ensure synchronization regardless of programmer's intention.

Is there a built-in functionality provided in ASP.NET? Or do I have to extend the `UserManager` class and centralize all the calls updating the database?

Comment: What's your email automation system? Is there a table in the database with users and the information which newsletters they should receive? If so then it would be simple

Comment: @user743414 it's Campaign Monitor but I don't see how that relates to the question. And yes, the table, of course, contains a column with that boolean value for each user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling an external API to keep in sync with your application data is a little more complicated than making a simple change in a domain model.

If you did this, would you call the API before or after you persist changes to the database? If before:

1. How do you make sure that the change is going to be accepted by the DB?
2. What if the API call fails? Do you refuse to update the DB?
3. What if the API call succeeds but the application crashes before updating the DB or the DB connection is temporarily lost?

If after:

1. The API could be unavailable (e.g. outage). How do you make sure this gets called later to keep things in sync?
2. The application crashes after updating the DB. How do you make sure the API gets called when it restarts?

There are a few different ways you could potentially solve this. However, bear in mind that by synchronising to an external system that you have lost the ACID semantics you may be used to and your application will have to deal with eventual consistency.

A simple solution would be to have another database table that acts as a queue of API calls to be made (it's important this is **ordered by time**). When the user's email is updated, you add a row as part of the DB transaction with the relevant details needed. This ensures the request to call the API is always recorded with an update.

Then you would have a separate process (or thread) that polls this table. You could use `pg_notify` to support push notifications rather than polling.

This process can read the row (in order) then call the relevant API to make the change in the external system. If it succeeds, it can remove the row. If it fails, it can try again using an exponential back-off. Continued failures should be logged for investigation.

The worst case scenario now is that you have *at-least-once* delivery semantics for updating the system (e.g. if API call succeeded but process crashed before removing the row then the call would be made again when process restarted). If you needed *at-most-once*, you would remove the row before attempting to make the call.

This is obviously glossing over some of the details and would need modified for a high through-put system but should hopefully explain some of the principles.

Answer (score 1):

I usually tackle this sort of thing with `LISTEN` and `NOTIFY` plus a queue table. You send a `NOTIFY` from a trigger when there's a change of interest, and insert a row into a queue table. A `LISTEN`ing connection notices the change, grabs the new row(s) from the queue table, actions them, and marks them as completed.

Instead of listen and notify you can just poll a queue table, listen and notify are an optimisation.

To make this *reliable*, either the actions you take must be in the same DB and done on the same connection as the update to the queue, or you need to use two-phase commit to synchronise actions. That's beyond the scope of this sort of answer, as you need a transaction resolver for crash recovery etc.

If it's safe to call the API multiple times (it's idempotent), then on failure midway through an operation it becomes fine to just execute all entries in the pending queue table again on crash recovery/restart/etc. You generally only need 2PC etc if you cannot safely repeat one of the actions.